# Pandas extract rows from df where df['col'] values match df2['col'] values

Tags: python

Finding this one difficult and would like to see if you can help, pls:

I have two `df`'s, `dfA` and `dfB`. In each there is a `telnum`, `file`, and `datetime` column, but only `dfA` contains a `name` column and only `dfA` has complete telephone number string values unlike `dfB` which sometimes has partially complete telephone numbers up to `x` of `n` digits, e.g. sometimes the int'l calling code is missing, other times a '0' is present instead of the int'l calling code, and other times neither int'l calling code or the leading '0' is present.

`dfA` also contains more data than `dfB` (<10 rows), but between the two there are complete `timestamp`, `file`, and `telnum` columns always with a date-time and string value respectively (even though `dfB['telnum']` is not fully complete as stated above).

What I want to do is extract the rows from `dfA` where `dfB['telnum']` matches `dfA['telnum']` but because `dfB['telnum']` is not always complete then I need to check for matches as a substring of `dfA['telnum']` too.

I would like the result to be `dfResult` but where the returned results have `dfA` values on the left and `dfB` on the right so that I can see the different `file` and `datetime` values.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I think I need an inner merge, e.g.

`pandas.merge(dfA, dfB, on='telnum', how='inner')`

However, because `dfB['telnum']` isn't always complete `telnum` string, the results are not complete. How can I get those that match between the two by checking if `dfB['telnum']` is a substring of `dfA['telnum']` as well?

Comment: Could you share what code you've already tried and why I didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing any complicated joins you need to clean your data.
I'm not sure how it is in your country, but in my country, if you remove the international prefix, or the leading zeroes, a phone number becomes 9 digits long.

Here's what I suggest you do:

1. Clean your 'telnum' columns:

```py
def remove_non_numbers(string):
    result = ""
    for char in string:
        if char.isnumeric():
            result += char
    return result

# Do this for both dataframes just in case
df["telnum"] = df["telnum"].apply(remove_non_numbers)
```

2. Remove any digits **before** the last 9:

```py
def limit9(string):
    if len(string) > 9:
        return string[-9:]
    return string

# Do this for both dataframes
df["telnum"] = df["telnum"].apply(limit9)
```

3. Now you can try to merge your cleaned DFs:

```py
dfResult = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, on='telnum', how='inner')
```

Good luck! Let me know if it works.

Comment: Nice approach. And I completely agree the solutions will largely depend on how the phone numbers look like in the data. Nevertheless, good job with the approach :)

Comment: Thanks. I was working on my code in the interim since my post, and I came to the same conclusion - remove the leading calling code or zero to leave behind the remaining digits then do the match on that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not provided any sample input or output, based on the description, I am making an attempt here. This is a multi fold problem and there can be many approaches depending on how your phone numbers look like.

Let me have two dataframes here (skipping your other columns): `dfA` and `dfB`.

dfA:

```
           telnum
0   0049123456789
1  00919444454555
2   0092789742893
```

dfB:

```
        telnum
0    123456789
1  09444454555
```

First, let's clean up the numbers in `dfB`. `dfB` can have numbers which are:

- number with ISD code - like `00918888888888`
- number with 0 in front of it `08888888888`
- number alone - `8888888888`

I am stripping off every number that starts with 0. So anything that has an international code `0091` becomes `091`, or has `091` and becomes `91`, and has `0888888888` becomes `888888888`. What this does is, since your dfA has the complete number with ISD code which I assume is off the form `00xxNNNNNNNN` - format, a substring match should be found easily.

```
dfB['telnum'] = dfB['telnum'].apply(lambda x : x[1:] if x.startswith("0") else x)
```

dfB now looks like (notice the first occuring 0 has been stripped):

```
       telnum  
0   123456789 
1  9444454555
```

Take all the numbers from dfB and convert them to a list:

```
tempList = dfB['telnum'].tolist()
```

Now look for the match in the other dataframe:

```
dfA[dfA.telnum.str.contains('|'.join(tempList))]
```

You should now get:

```
           telnum
0   0049123456789
1  00919444454555
```

So you have found those numbers for which you got a match. You can now proceed with these rows and perform the necessary join with other columns or anything you want.